# cURL on PHP being curiously silent

Tags: php, curl

OK so after struggling for a while trying to get cURL to fetch a password protected XML file, and getting absolutely nothing from it, I tried dumbing down my code to see what *would* work. It turns out nothing. Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init("www.google.com");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

And cURL is SILENT. I mean nothing prints to the page. I definitely have it enabled, my phpinfo looks like this:

```
cURL support            enabled
cURL Information            libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8a zlib/1.2.3
```

Running php 5.2 on a Windows NT server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Be sure you are allowed to actually use `curl` functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

You're telling cURL to return the result of the transfer instead of echoing it (the default).  So either remove that line, or do something like this:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $result;
}
```

If you're getting an SSL error as you point out in your comments, you can set another option on the cURL handle to disable checking the certificate:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Comment: Ah , I had left that in from when I was trying to parse an XML file and put it into a variable. OK my problem is actually completely different and this post is stupid, sorry.

Comment: OK then here's a head scratcher, I've changed the code to:

`$ch = curl_init("https://servicewithapi.com/file.xml");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);`

with obvious substitutions, but still nothing. Just a white page with no output.

Comment: Ah I'm getting something now, apparently:

Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. I will look into this, thanks.